# is it a security risk to have php files with config in the public folder?

Tags: php, .htaccess, wordpress

There is a config.php in my root folder.
Users can access `domain.com/config.php`
However the file does not echo/print any of the config.
Do I still need to deny in some .htaccess rule, or is it safe as is?

In particular it is a wordpress app and I just realized that I can open wp-config.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It wouldn't be the first time a web server fails with PHP handler for some reason (temporary misconfiguration, upgrade...). If there's any risk that the page might even once get loaded as a plain text instead of handled as a script, you'll end up revealing your passwords.

More secure than any `.htaccess` restriction would be keeping the configuration file outside document root (for example in `~/conf/` instead of `~/public_html/`). The CMS or another application won't even recognize any difference if you a) `include()` the file on its original location and b) the PHP has access to both files even when the web server hasn't.